# Amazon Connect - Invoke Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

[get_customer_input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZzxc.png)
[ReasonForCalling_Play_prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbsFH.png)

Lambda function returns properly when testing Lex chatbot. 
Invoking the function through Amazon Connect results in an Error. 
Any ideas on how to save the return from Lambda in Connect with proper formatting? * Updated to add updated lambda code and Lex configuration image.

```
Lambda Code:

    console.log('Loading event');
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });


    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

        var ssn = event.currentIntent.slots.userSSN;
        var mySecret = event.currentIntent.slots.secretWord;


        var params = {

            TableName: 'users',
            Key: {
                "fourDigSSN": {
                    "N": ssn
                },
                "mySecretWord": {
                    "S": mySecret
                }
            },
            AttributesToGet: ["accountBalance"]
        };

        db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(" It didn't work and here is the error " + err); // an error occurred
            }
            else
                callback(null, {
                    "sessionAttributes":{
                        "accountBal": data.Item.accountBalance.N
                    },
                    "dialogAction": {
                        "type": "ConfirmIntent",
                        "message": {
                            "contentType": "PlainText",
                            "content": "Your account has been verified. Your account balance is " + data.Item.accountBalance.N + "."

                        },
                        "intentName": "ReasonForCalling",
                        "slots": {
                            "userSSN": ssn,
                            "secretWord": mySecret
                        }
                    }

                });
                // var accountBal = data.Item.accountBalance.N;
                // //console.log("GetDBItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                // callback(null, {accountBalance : accountBal});
        });



    };

[lex_configuration][1]
[connect_contact_flow][2]
[connect_lambda_Details][3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Amazon Connect contact flow appears to be referencing $.External.(something) after matching the "ReasonForCalling" intent.  $.External is only used if Amazon Connect is calling upon a Lambda function directly.  In your case, Amazon Connect is interacting with Lex.  Lex is calling Lambda, so any response you get back to Amazon Connect will be coming from Lex, not Lambda.  In order for Amazon Connect to read back something from Lex, you will need to use one of the following in your Play prompt step:

- $.Lex.IntentName
- $.Lex.Slots.(slotName)
- $.Lex.SessionAttributes.(sessionAttributeKey)

Option1: You can configure Lex to insert the Account Balance into a slot called "AccountBal", then "return parameters to client". From there, Amazon Connect can access that value as $.Lex.Slots.AccountBal.

Option2: If you want Amazon Connect to interact directly to Lambda, you can use Lex to collect userSSN and secretWord and then build a separate Lambda function that Amazon Connect calls directly using an "Invoke AWS Lambda Function" step to perform the database lookup.  With this method, you would be receiving a response directly from Lambda and can reference it as $.External.accountBalance.

EDITED ----------

Your callback has DialogAction type set as "ConfirmIntent" so Lex is most likely still expecting some user response.  I doubt Amazon Connect is even getting anything back from Lex.  Try updating the callback to something like the following so Lex will finish fulfillment and return to Amazon Connect:

```js
callback(null, {
    "sessionAttributes":{
        "accountBal": data.Item.accountBalance.N
    },
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "Your account has been verified. Your account balance is " + data.Item.accountBalance.N + "."

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference in Amazon Connect interacting with only Lex versus Lambda. Can you explain Option 1 a little more? Do I just add AccountBal to Slot list like I have userSSN and secretWord?

Comment: Also, I have added the account balance as a session attribute in the Lambda function. "accountBal": data.Item.accountBalance.N -------------------I am trying to use $.Lex.SessionAttributes.accountBal in the play prompt from the get input node. But, the customer input is going straight to an error instead of intent to play prompt.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you have Lex setup?  Need to understand if you are calling Lambda as Validation Codehook or Fulfillment or both, what slots you have, etc.  Provide your updated Lambda code as well.  Then maybe I can mock it up and a provide more specific answer.

Comment: Updated the Lambda code. Here is the link for the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7mb0.png

Comment: Edited answer above.  I mocked up something similar in my instance and it is working correctly.

Comment: I made the change in Lambda. Still getting the same error when calling though. Updated the Contact Flow pics from connect. It fails there.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZzxc.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbsFH.png

Comment: In which logs are you seeing the error (Lambda or Connect) and what is the exact error you are experiencing?

Comment: The error is in Connect. So the Get customer input block is failing. You can call the number 216-485-2654. it will ask why you're calling: account balance, last four of SSN: 4532, secret word: Dog. There's three options automatically configured for the block, ReasonForCalling, Default, and Error.

Comment: Can you insert a "Set logging behavior" step immediately after the entry point of your contact flow?  This will allow a more descriptive error to show up in CloudWatch.  You will need to make sure that Logging is enabled for your Amazon Connect instance.  If you go to your instance setup, click on "Contact Flows" on the left and you will see a checkbox on the right to enable contact flow logs.